# mongodb count on aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get a count on my aggregation but for some reason I'm getting an error saying "$count" is an unrecognized aggregation stage.
I've tried this with both mongo 3.0 and 3.4 shells

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
   {$match:{'field1': "abc"}},
   {$count:"mycount"}
])
```

Comment: Can you make sure you are  running  shell against 3.4 mongod server instance ? Run db.version() on shell to check.

Comment: the mongod version is actually 3.0.11 but the client i'm using is 3.4 so that might explain why

Answer (score 1):

**$count** should work in mongoDB 3.4

You can use **$group** to count in your aggregation pipeline in lower versions:

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
   {$match: {'field1': "abc"}},
   {$group: {
      _id : null, 
      aggregationCount : {$sum : 1}
   }}
])
```

Comment: what do you think will return faster: that or a find query that essentially does the same thing?
db.collection1.find({'field1':"abc"}).count()

Comment: the aggregation is taking awfully long even though 'field1' (which is in fact nested) is indexed

Comment: @IsaacBok If the query is running but taking a long time, that's a different issue. You should look into it with the [Explain Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) functionality.